# Таймер обратного отсчёта в консоли

Tags: c++, c

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы шел вывод не так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Нужно чтобы вывод был все время в одной строке

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это зависит от терминала. Скорее всего, достаточно заканчивать (или начинать) строку на `\r` вместо `\n`.

Например, на C++ под Windows работает такая конструкция:

```
cout << "\r12:54" << flush();
```

Для других систем (Linux?) вам могут понадобиться другие символы.

---

Обновление: Вроде бы и в Linux'е должно работать.

---

Для точного управления позиционированием текста в консоли вам нужны системные библиотеки. Под Windows это [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) из WinAPI, для POSIX-систем подойдёт библиотека ncurses.

Comment: `\r` работает не во всех эмуляторах терминала (на линуксе)

Comment: @zenden2k: Угу. Универсальное решение — это ncurses. Ещё есть какие-то ужасные ESC-последовательности.

Comment: @zenden2k: Напишете альтернативный ответ?

Comment: Мне самому нужен ответ. Тянуть всю библиотеку ncurses и (PDcurses на винде) ради вывода одной тоже не хочется.

Comment: @zenden2k: А вам только `\r` эмулировать, или полное управление курсором?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что ncurses нужна для рисования всяких окошек в консоли, типа как у mc или far. А всё, что мне нужно - возможность вернуться на `n` строчек назад.

Comment: @zenden2k: А какой у вас терминал? Что говорит `echo $TERM`?

Comment: Выводит `xterm`. Стандартный терминал Elementary OS

Comment: @zenden2k: А [ANSI-коды](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) поддерживает?